# Importing csv in fresh sqlite3 to work with new project django 2.1

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, sqlite

I really didn't know how to phrase that question properly, but hopefully I can make things clear here.

My initial goal was to import a CSV file, inside of my new sqlite3 database, and have my app model.py work with it,

This is what the table looks like (this was imported from a csv file)
[image]

I renamed the Table to fit the naming format that the app would take

appname: locate

Here is a picture of the locate/model.py file:
[image]

I named each variable to be identical with the tables that were in my imported CSV file

After this I of course placed the app inside my settings and ran a migration and got hit with the following error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: there is already another table or index with this name: locate_professor
```

Does anyone know how I would be able to properly configure this!! 
thanks!

Comment: If you are going to use xls too try this little tool: https://github.com/bloodwithmilk25/django-xlspopulator

Comment: Just saw your answer, I do have a xls version of the file so I'll just attempt your method in a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may need migrate the model before you imported the csv file.
or you can set the managed of the model to be false.
The second way is not recommended.

Comment: I'll try that but how would I be able to put the information inside of those fields, like I can migrate the model and get all the necessary fields, but how would I populate the fields with my pre-existing data

Comment: you can write a data import  script or use a db GUI client.

Comment: I used the xlspopulator, I had these in excel format before converting them into csv so it worked out thanks though